# Python PyPDF2 - getpage multiple pages

Tags: python, pypdf

How do I pass in muliple page numbers to extract for a single file? I am able to use .getpage(pageNum) to add a single page, but I would like to pass in multiple page numbers into the argument. I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried getting pages in a loop?

Comment: @Furkan yes, that worked. Took some playing around with it, but finally got it dialed in.

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, I got it to work. For those looking for an answer:

1. I stripped the text out of the pdf and put the info that I needed in a dictionary.
2. The key is an item number and the values were the pages that related to each item - there's multiple pages for each item number and values are a list.
3. The second 'for' loop in the block loops through the values of each item and adds however many pages need to be added to the file.

Hope this helps

```
with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as infile:
reader = PdfFileReader(infile)

for x, y in dic_name.items():
    writer = PdfFileWriter()
    with open(x +'.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
        for i in y:
            writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i-1))
        writer.write(outfile)
        outfile.close()
```